# Apache rejecting PUT requests to reverse proxy with 405 error

Tags: apache, express, reverse-proxy

I'm having trouble using apache as a reverse proxy on top of a Node JS/Express REST API.

When i make a PUT request to the URL I'm proxying, apache seems to respond with a 405 Method not allowed response instead of forwarding the request to the service. I can make GET and POST requests without issues.

If I send the request directly to the API(http://ip-address:port) everything works as normal. Also, if i make the request from the server itself to the domain it works fine.

CORS is disabled in the API.

```
<VirtualHost example.domain.local:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.40:9020/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.40:9020/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I inspect the request I can see that the HTTP allow header is set to GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE. So i tried changing it with directives inside the virtual host directive.

```
<Proxy "*">
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  AllowMethods GET PUT DELETE POST
</Proxy>
```

But there was no change. I also tried LimitExcept directive inside  the Proxy directive but that didn't make a difference.

I also went through all of httpd.conf but didn't see anything suspicious configured there.

I'm completely stuck, anyone familiar with this sort of problem?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? Can you please post it here if you did, or link to it?

Comment: Unfortunately when i look at the config now it's no different. But this is working at the moment as far as i know. But i think it had something to do with Allow from all directive, since this was Apache 2.4 not 2.2. So it had to be "Require all granted" instead.

Comment: Thank @GrimurD I got it to work, it was a mismatch in the paths that caused the request to go to a different URI for me.

Comment: I think I just had the same problem just with a little different setup. My Apache is running as a reverse proxy as well and I have asp.net-core api as backend (instead of node-js). My solution was that the URI used for doing the PUT request had some letters in upper casing (because someone hard coded that address like this) but they should have been all lower-case. When I changed them to lower-case it resulted in the PUT to work.

Comment: The Message Apache gives here may make sense on a lower technical level, but on the level we are talking about here it would have been better if it returned that the URI is invalid alltogether instead of saying 'PUT' is not allowed.